# Where does Xcode 8 download the developer documentation to?

Tags: xcode, documentation

I know that Xcode downloads a lot of developer documentation for everything from Objective-C to Swift on to your mac hard drive if you choose to download the developer documentation.

I've navigated to the directory before, but I didn't note down its location, and now I am having trouble finding it. It had PDF versions of a lot of documentation which is available on the Apple website.

Any idea what the location is ? This question is posted on stackoverflow.com, because the people who will know the answer are programmers who visit this site, as opposed to superuser.

EDIT: Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.docset is not what I am looking for. While it has some documentation, it is not the treasure trove that contains documentation on Objective-C, Swift, Memory management and much much more....that is all stored in some other location... how to find it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is found here:

~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation

Comment: You can use `~` instead of `/Users/yourusername`