# Is it possible to dump xcode 9.2 developer documentation as structure data?

Tags: ios, xcode9

Is it possible to dump the **whole** xcode **9.2** developer documentation as structure data ?

For the data in the screenshot,

[image]

The expected output is:

```
{
 'framework':'UIKit',
 'class_name':'UIApplication',
 'method_name':'registerForRemoteNotifications'
}
```

Thanks for suggestion in advance.

Comment: You can find the documentation there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648188/where-does-xcode-8-download-the-developer-documentation-to I guess you can parse then the documentation.

Comment: @Larme I have read that thread before, but it for xcode 8. It seems that xcode 9 has the documentation integrated directly, but I can not find it's location on the disk :(